# Ajax tool kit pop up is not working in VS 2010 when window is updated to windows 11

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax

my ajax tool kit is not working when windows is updated to 11 before updating everything is working fine. After the update I cant use ajax calendar it is not popping up in my local project asp.net . I am using visual studio 2010 is there any solution please help me. but in live I can use ajax calendar in my test I cant use Ajax

Comment: You could try clearing your browser cache (try ctrl-ft while in the browser - that can force a browser code cache reload). Perhaps a re install of the ajaxtoolkit might help? Does a new test page work? Really hard to tell here unless you outline some things you already attempted

Comment: Are you stuck using visual studio 2010? That's quite an old IDE at this point.